# Schedule apex every second week

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, cron

Is there a way to schedule an apex class(schedulable of course) to run every second week?

I thought I could do it in the UI by scheduling 2 jobs for 2nd and 4rd Friday of the month, but the moment I try to schedule the second one I get the error:

> Error: This Apex class is already scheduled for execution.

I have seen [this answer](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092rTIAQ), but that doesn't really fit my needs. My batch should only start executing every second Friday after work hours.

I was also thinking about using cron, but couldn't find a way to schedule it for every second and fourth Friday of the month.

Comment: what about this cron: 0 1 8-14,21-28 * 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the cron expressions for the schedule.

**Every 2nd Friday of a Month at 8 PM**

```
0 0 20 ? 1/1 FRI#2 *
```

**Every 4th Friday of a Month at 8 PM**

```
0 0 20 ? 1/1 FRI#4 *
```

**The code to run in developer console anonymous block to schedule the jobs**

```
System.schedule('2nd Friday Schedule', '0 0 20 ? 1/1 FRI#2 *', new YourApexClass());
System.schedule('4th Friday Schedule', '0 0 20 ? 1/1 FRI#4 *', new YourApexClass());
```