# Cron expression to run Job every second Friday

Tags: scheduled-apex, cron

I need to schedule my class to run **every two weeks on Friday.**

I see [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/198057/schedule-apex-every-second-week) in questions.

However It is **not** excactly what I want.

And I can not came up with an idea hot to write a **cron expression** for this : based on :

- [topic](https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/using-cron-expression-in-salesforce/)
- [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm)

**Maybe someone has already done something similar ?**

Any help will be appreciated.

thank you

Comment: When you say [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/198057/schedule-apex-every-second-week) is not exactly what you want, are you looking to only ever schedule a single instance of the class or what is your desired solution?

Comment: @TSmith  I need to schedule EVERY TWO WEEKS . NOT on the 2nd Friday and on 4th Friday of month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only offer a solution by scheduling two instances of your class, one on the 2nd Friday of Month, the other on 4th Friday of month.

- 2nd Friday : `0 0 0 ? 1/1 FRI#2 *`
- 4th Friday : `0 0 0 ? 1/1 FRI#4 *`

As you can see, `FRI#N` can be changed if you wish to go with 1st and 3rd Friday also.

I would note that the impact of a month with 5 Fridays should be tested on your side.

Comment: It's worth noting that `0 0 0 * * FRI#2,FRI#4 *` would work, except that *System.StringException: Support for specifying multiple "nth" days is not implemented.* Two jobs is the way to go here, unfortunately.

Comment: @sfdcfox Ok, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to schedule two jobs.

One with `0 0 8 ? 1/1 FRI#2 *`

and second with `0 0 8 ? 1/1 FRI#4 *`

Change the `8` as per your time as it denotes the time at which the job will run.